# Pass div to javascript function and change its style

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pass a div's id to a javascript function that does something simple, like change the background color of the div.

Weird thing is, my code works in the w3schools.com Tryit editor, but not in JSFiddle. It also doesn't work in my compiler (Coda 2).

Is this even the right way of going about this? Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeBackgroundColor(asdf)
{
    asdf.style.backgroundColor = "#fff000";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv" style="background:red"> this is my div </div>
<button onclick="changeBackgroundColor(myDiv)"> Set background color </button>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's the JSFiddle stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/BH9Rs/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `document.getElementById` to get the element from the id

```
function changeBackgroundColor(asdf){
    document.getElementById(asdf).style.backgroundColor = "#fff000";
}
```

and pass the id like this (in single quotes)

```
<button onclick="changeBackgroundColor('myDiv')">
```

And in your fiddle put your function inside the `Head` section. 
*(select no-wrap in Head) at left side Framework and Extension option*

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BH9Rs/4/)

Comment: 'myDiv' This single quote saved my life. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the script placement combo to `no wrap - in <head>` (second combo box on the left panel)

Answer (score 0):

`myDiv` is an unknown identifier.

Use `document.getElementById()` in order to refer to your div:

```
<button onclick="changeBackgroundColor(document.getElementById('myDiv'))"> Set background color </button>
```

In addition, you have to move your JS code in your HTML due to the jsFiddle environment: http://jsfiddle.net/BH9Rs/1/

```
<script>
    function changeBackgroundColor(asdf) {
        asdf.style.backgroundColor = "#fff000";
    }
</script>
<div id="myDiv" style="background:red">this is my div</div>
<button onclick="changeBackgroundColor(document.getElementById('myDiv'))">Set background color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles and inline click events? boo.

```
<div id="myDiv"> this is my div </div>
<button id="clickMe"> Set background color </button>

<script>
    document.getElementById('clickMe').onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('myDiv').style.backgroundColor = '#fff000';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Old DOM events? Boo :D

Comment: @ComFreek yeah i figured id go baby steps, rather than show `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You mast do so:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeBackgroundColor(asdf)
{
    document.getElementById(asdf).style.backgroundColor = "#fff000";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv" style="background:red"> this is my div </div>
<button onclick="changeBackgroundColor('myDiv')"> Set background color </button>

</body>
</html>
```